# Libevent 2 - write callback / infinite loop

Tags: libevent

I'm playing with Libevent as a server and I'm having a problem

Basically I'm using the example at the bottom of this page, http://www.wangafu.net/~nickm/libevent-book/Ref6_bufferevent.html:
I have the `main/accept/readcb` working well - however trying to understand the `writecb`.

Before I go further I want to make sure I have this correct.

When a client send (`curl in this instance`) sends some `JSON`, this is called in the `read_callback`, when I want to write back to the `curl` I use the `write_callback`.

the problem I have in short, when I do a curl with `json`. It requests that the server sends a http/1.1 100 continue before sending the `JSON`. I could ignore that but would rather not.

So this is what I have for my write callback:

```
void writecb(struct bufferevent *bev, void *ctx){
   struct evbuffer *tmp = evbuffer_new();
   evbuffer_add_printf(tmp, "HTTP/1.1 100 Continue\r\n\r\n");
   bufferevent_write_buffer(bev, tmp);
   evbuffer_free(tmp);
   printf("finish sending data back to client!\n");
}
```

What happens is when I do a `curl` statement:

`curl -vv -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data @test.json http://localhost:40714`

On the console there is an infinite loop.

However if I put this code within the `readcb`, it works like a charm. So my question, what is the point of `writecb`? Is it when you finalize a write and what to close a connection you send 'stuff'?

Answer (score 0):

The point of `writecb` is opposite to `readcb`: writecb is invoked by libevent automatically when there is enough room in the OUTPUT side of bufferevent for some new data to be written into.

Here you described a good example of infinite loop:

- writecb was invoked by libevent (because there is enough room on OUTPUT side)
- inside writecb you generating new data and writing it into the OUTPUT by `bufferevent_write_buffer`. Then writecb returns context back to libevent main loop.
- libevent is passing all the data from OUTPUT to the kernel. And when done, libevent sees that a free place became available in OUTPUT buffer. This generates next `writecb` event and the callback is invoked again... And here is the infinite loop.